# MySQL GRANT control

Tags: mysql, permissions

How can I write a script to automate MySQL database grants in a very easy way?

I have a config file that contains the grant changes I want to make.  I want the script to read the config file, and make any necessary changes to the access rights as specified in the config file.  Essentially, I want the target rights to match the rights in the config file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question? You want to write a script (so you need to choose a language: perl,python,etc). Then you code the logic you want around the `SHOW GRANTS`, `GRANT`, and `REVOKE` sql commands through the mysql command line.

Answer (score 1):

How about a script that runs [SHOW GRANTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html), parses the results, and compares it to what it parsed from your config file.  Given that info, you can GRANT or REVOKE until the two lists match.